# Oracle 11gR2 RAC unable to connect to SCAN address

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rac

I'm having a problem with my RAC environment. I am using RedHat 6, Oracle 11.2.0.4 SE. Have a 2 node RAC setup using ASM.

When connecting using SQL Developer, i can connect to my service (dev1.xxxx-dmz.local) if i connection directly to either of my cluster nodes, but when i try and use the cluster name i get the following message

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

i have the following DNS setup 
csya-or-cluster with 3 ip addresses (172.28.1.191, 192, 193)
csya-orarac1 (172.28.1.91)
csya-orarac1-vip (172.28.1.95)
csya-orarac2 (172.28.1.92)
csya-orarac2-vip (172.28.1.96)

output

```
$ORACLE_GRID/bin/srvctl status scan
SCAN VIP scan1 is enabled
SCAN VIP scan1 is running on node csya-orarac2
SCAN VIP scan2 is enabled
SCAN VIP scan2 is running on node csya-orarac1
SCAN VIP scan3 is enabled
SCAN VIP scan3 is running on node csya-orarac1

$ORACLE_GRID/bin/srvctl status scan_listener
SCAN Listener LISTENER_SCAN1 is enabled
SCAN listener LISTENER_SCAN1 is running on node csya-orarac2
SCAN Listener LISTENER_SCAN2 is enabled
SCAN listener LISTENER_SCAN2 is running on node csya-orarac1
SCAN Listener LISTENER_SCAN3 is enabled
SCAN listener LISTENER_SCAN3 is running on node csya-orarac1
```

csya-orarac1

```
./lsnrctl status listener

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 08-MAY-2015 12:05:16
Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                08-MAY-2015 11:30:10
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 35 min. 6 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/csya-orarac1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=LISTENER)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.28.1.91)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.28.1.95)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "+ASM" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "dev1.xxxx-dmz.local" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "dev11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "dev1XDB.xxxx-dmz.local" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "dev11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

csya-orarac1

```
./lsnrctl status listener_scan2
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 08-MAY-2015 12:06:48


Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER_SCAN2)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER_SCAN2
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                08-MAY-2015 11:30:04
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 36 min. 44 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/log/diag/tnslsnr/csya-orarac1/listener_scan2/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=LISTENER_SCAN2)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.28.1.192)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "dev1.xxxx-dmz.local" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "dev11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "dev12", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "dev1XDB.xxxx-dmz.local" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "dev11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "dev12", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

csya-orarac1

```
./lsnrctl status listener_scan3

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 08-MAY-2015 12:10:50

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER_SCAN3)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER_SCAN3
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                08-MAY-2015 11:30:05
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 40 min. 44 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/log/diag/tnslsnr/csya-orarac1/listener_scan3/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=LISTENER_SCAN3)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.28.1.191)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "dev1.xxxx-dmz.local" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "dev11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "dev12", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "dev1XDB.xxxx-dmz.local" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "dev11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "dev12", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

csya-orarac1

```
nslookup csya-or-cluster
Server:         172.28.1.42
Address:        172.28.1.42#53

Name:   csya-or-cluster.xxxx-dmz.local
Address: 172.28.1.191
Name:   csya-or-cluster.xxxx-dmz.local
Address: 172.28.1.193
Name:   csya-or-cluster.xxxx-dmz.local
Address: 172.28.1.192
```

csya-orarac2

```
./lsnrctl status listener_scan1

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 08-MAY-2015 12:07:51

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER_SCAN1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER_SCAN1
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                08-MAY-2015 11:30:02
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 37 min. 49 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/log/diag/tnslsnr/csya-orarac2/listener_scan1/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=LISTENER_SCAN1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.28.1.193)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "dev1.xxxx-dmz.local" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "dev11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "dev12", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "dev1XDB.xxxx-dmz.local" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "dev11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "dev12", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

csya-orarac2

```
nslookup csya-or-cluster
Server:         172.28.1.42
Address:        172.28.1.42#53

Name:   csya-or-cluster.xxxx-dmz.local
Address: 172.28.1.193
Name:   csya-or-cluster.xxxx-dmz.local
Address: 172.28.1.191
Name:   csya-or-cluster.xxxx-dmz.local
Address: 172.28.1.192
```

i can connect locally using sqlplus with the following from either node

```
sqlplus system/xxxxxxx@csya-or-cluster.xxxx-dmz.local:1521/dev1.xxxx-dmz.local
```

the listener parameters on csya-orarac1 are set as

```
SQL> show parameter _listener

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
local_listener                       string      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(AD
                                                 DRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx
                                                 -orarac1.xxxx-dmz.local)(PORT=
                                                 1521))))
remote_listener                      string      csya-or-cluster.xxxx-dmz.local
                                                 :1521
```

the listener parameters on csya-orarac2 are set as

```
SQL> show parameter _listener

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
local_listener                       string      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(AD
                                                 DRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=csya
                                                 -orarac2.xxxx-dmz.local)(PORT=
                                                 1521))))
remote_listener                      string      csya-or-cluster.xxxx-dmz.local
                                                 :1521
```

hosts file on both nodes

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.28.92   rhproxy.xxxxxxxxx.com

#Public Host Names
172.28.1.91     csya-orarac1.xxxx-dmz.local csya-orarac1
172.28.1.92     csya-orarac2.xxxx-dmz.local csya-orarac2

#Private Host Names
172.28.97.91    csya-orarac1-priv.xxxx-dmz.local csya-orarac1-priv
172.28.97.92    csya-orarac2-priv.xxxx-dmz.local csya-orarac2-priv

#Virtual Host Names
172.28.1.95     csya-orarac1-vip.xxxx-dmz.local csya-orarac1-vip
172.28.1.96     csya-orarac2-vip.xxxx-dmz.local csya-orarac2-vip

172.28.1.229    rhproxy rhproxy.xxxxxxxxxx.com
```

hopefully one of you can see what is wrong, i've seen other people have similar problems online, but none of the solutions they have posted seem to work for me.

thanks

Comment: Are you accessing cluster from SQL Developer directly or via some kind of NAT. Also does your PC correctly resolve all the DNS names from cluster? And you can try to tcpdump or wireshark (if your PC runs Windows) traffic and find where your SQL Developer tries and fails to connect.

Comment: Hi, i'm accessing SQL Developer directly from a windows environment. Yes DNS is resolving correctly, and nslookup on csya-ora-cluster.xxxx-dmz.local resolves and cycles through the 3 ip addresses assigned.

I'm not really allowed to install anything like tcpdump or wireshark, is there anything else you can suggest which is built into Windows?

Comment: Can you ping the SCAN address.

Comment: yep, i can ping the SCAN. This is something i am unclear on, is there a difference between the SCAN and the cluster? on our DNS server i have the cluster entries with 3 ip address, but from the oracle doc it seems to say the SCAN is a different beast altogether, and mentions that my default the scan is mycluster-scan, is this correct, do i need to have DNS entries for mycluster-scan as well as mycluster?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the output, the problem exists on the client side. When you connect to the SCAN address, the SCAN listener forwards your request to one of the local listeners listening on the VIP addresses. If you check the output of `lsnrctl services listener_scan1`, you can see this at the `(HOST=...)` entry for each service. If the client can't resolve the VIP name, the connection attempt will fail. So we are back to the original question from @Mindaugas Riauba: "does your PC correctly resolve **all** the DNS names from cluster?" Not just the SCAN, but VIPs also.

Comment: Hi, yes from the client i can resolve the node VIPs by their name and their IP. I can also resolve the cluster name and it's 3 IPs. So is there a difference between the cluster name and the SCAN which i am misunderstanding. 
Thanks

Comment: The cluster name and SCAN name are different by default. You can check the cluster name by: `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/cemutlo -n` and SCAN name by: `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/srvctl config scan`, and the SCAN name/address should be used for client connections. It's really easy though to check if it is a name resolution error. If your client can resolve the name returned by the SCAN listener (e.g. `lsnrctl services listener_scan1`, `(HOST=...)`) and you can connect that name directly, then name resolution works as intended.

Comment: Ok, so my cluster name is "csya-or-cluster" and the SCAN name is "csya-or-cluster.xxxx-dmz.local". The client can resolve the HOST entry of 172.28.1.191 to the SCAN name. But when i use the SCAN name or one of its IPs in my connection string i fail to connect

Comment: something i have discovered, that even though from the client i can ping the node-vip, when i try and connect using "sqlplus system/xxxxxxx@node1-vip.xxxx-dmz.local:1521/dev1.xxxxx-dmz.local the connection attempt times out. So it looks like there may be a problem with the local listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the VIP addresses not being allowed to be accessed via port 1521 due to our firewall policy. These IPs are now permitted and the problem has been resolved. thanks to [Balazs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/28019/balazs-papp) for all the help.